# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: SalesforceIQIntegration User cannot be edited

Tags: visual-workflow, process-automation

I have created a flow to update user fields with according to contact fields, whenever a contact is updated. I receive the following error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: SalesforceIQIntegration User cannot be edited. Although the license of the user is Partner Community License and not integrated user. I am a system admin and have all access to the user fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your Flow is trying to update the SalesforceIQIntegration User. However this is a standard user that comes with certain Salesforce orgs and cannot be edited.